# BeautifulSoup Pretify list to Pandas DF

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am learning how to use bs4 and pandas together and I got the elements I wanted, but not in the form I wished.

My current code gives me a list 'prettified'.

```
        soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('div', class_='dataTables_scrollBody')
        df_list = pd.read_html(table.prettify())
        print(df_list)

[    N° Neg.  Preço  Qtd.  N° Cp Comprador   Vendedor  N° Vd   Agressor      Hora
0     21300   9399     1      3        XP  Easynvest     90  COMPRADOR  14:04:49
1     21290   9399    16      3        XP  Easynvest     90  COMPRADOR  14:04:49]
```

How do i convert this 'list' to a Dataframe in pandas that will be able to export to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_html` returns a list of dataframes, you can select the one that you want just accessing by its index. As you have only one table you should obtain `df_list[0]`